# Why am I obtaining this inconsistent accessibility error on the return type of a method?

Tags: c#

I am working on a .NET project. In a DAO class (using ADO.NET but this is not important) I have a method like this:

```
public static List<Inoltro> GetListaInoltriUltimiGiorni(int IdUor, string Protocollista, int NumeroGiorni, DBConnection config)
{
    string query = PROT_INOLTRO.INOLTRI_ULTIMI_N_GIORNI_BY_UOR_AND_PROTOCOLLISTA;

    List<Inoltro> result = new List<Inoltro>();

    using (SqlConnection con = ArxeiaConnection.getARXEIAStringConnection(config.Tenant + "_" + config.Database))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUor", IdUor);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Protocollista", Protocollista);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroGiorni", NumeroGiorni);

                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        // Read advances to the next row.
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            .........................................
                            .........................................
                            .........................................
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                con.Close();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

As you can see I am creating and returning this object:

```
List<Inoltro> result = new List<Inoltro>();
```

The problem is that Visual studio give me the following error on this method signature:

> Inconsistent accessibility: return type `List<Inoltro>` is less accessible than method MyClass.GetListaInoltriUltimiGiorni(....)

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the defined accessibility of `Inoltro` ? If `Inoltro` isn't `public`, you can't return `List<Inoltro>` from a `public` method (note: this gets a bit more complex if you have nested types with different accessibilities)

Comment: The error message got mangled, edited.  It isn't complaining about List, it is Inoltro that's the problem.  You must make it public.

Comment: `throw ex;`  Also, change this to just `throw;`.  The way you're doing it will throw away the call stack.

Comment: @Amy The connection is *already* being closed by the `using` anyway, so the whole `try/catch` can just go away entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is `public` but `Inoltro` is `internal`. You cannot have a `public` method that exposes an `internal` type. Either make the method `internal` or the type `public`.

While we are looking at your code, a few things come to mind.

First, the `try catch` is unnecessary, since the `using` already does a `Close` on the connection if an exception is thrown. Eliminate the `try catch`.

Second, for your future reference, never say `throw ex;` in a `catch`.  Say `throw;` to re-throw an exception. The difference is subtle. `throw;` re-throws the exact exception that was caught. `throw ex;` re-throws the exception but resets the stack trace to the current trace, not the original trace.

The only time you want to do `throw ex;` is when you *deliberately* want to obscure where an exception came from, for instance, because there is a trust boundary between the current code and the caller. However, in that case it would be better still to throw a new, generic exception.

Third, I don't understand why you have both a `while` and an `if` to check to see if the set has rows. Surely if the set is empty then the `Read` will return false, so there was never a need for the `if`, right?

Fourth, this is just a style point; normally we would format

```
using (SqlConnection con = ArxeiaConnection.getARXEIAStringConnection(config.Tenant + "_" + config.Database))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
```

as

```
using (SqlConnection con = ArxeiaConnection.getARXEIAStringConnection(config.Tenant + "_" + config.Database))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
```

It is common to have a `using` whose body is only another `using`, and in that scenario the unnecessary braces and indentation do not make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Note that removing `if(reader.HasRows)` introduces a behavioral difference.  If your SQL query throws an exception (e.g., `select 1/0;`), `HasRows` will return false whereas `Read()` will throw an exception.  Personally, I prefer callers to be able to distinguish between "no results" and "something went wrong", so I recommend against checking `HasRows`.  Take note that `HasRows` being `true` does not guarantee against an exception (i.e., if the exception is not triggered on the first row), so checking `HasRows` may lead to inconsistent exception-triggering behavior).

Comment: @Brian: Thanks so much for that comment! That's a subtle and interesting distinction.